# Variable value not updating in string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this class called "DialogueLines.cs" where I have a list of public static strings. The problem is that when I access this particular string:

```
public static volatile string cutscene_introHurt7 = "* " + Manager.playerName + " huh?\n  That's a nice name.";
```

The value of `Manager.playerName` is not correct. At the beginning, the value of the playerName is set to "Garrett". When updated to something else, such as "Zip", the dialogue will still say:
`* Garrett, huh? That's a nice name.` I've also checked with Debug.Log() statements to make sure the name is changing correctly. I assume it's because the string isn't being updated with the correct variable value. As you can see, I've already tried sticking the volatile keyword onto the string with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting the value for Manager.playerName?

Comment: In an IEnumerator. The value updates fine as shown by Debug.Log statements regarding the value and also other text fields being updated fine. It's simply this one string that doesn't have the correct value somehow. Could it be because it's static, or how can I force a refresh or somethin'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to behaviour of `static`. The static will pre-compile the string, meaning that even if you change username, your pre-compiled string will not change.

You can however, simply change the string. By doing the whole assignment again before you use it

```
cutscene_introHurt7 = "* " + Manager.playerName + " huh?\n  That's a nice name.";
```

However, you might want to consider just making it non static if possible. After which your intended behaviour would work.

Below a sample console application to see the static solution in action

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static string playerName = "GARRET";
    // This will be concatonated to 1 string on runtime "* GARRET huh? \m That's a nice name."
    public static volatile string cutscene_introHurt7 = "* " + playerName + " huh?\n  That's a nice name.";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // We write the intended string
        Console.WriteLine(cutscene_introHurt7);
        // We change the name, but the string is still compiled
        playerName = "Hello world!";
        // Will give the same result as before
        Console.WriteLine(cutscene_introHurt7);
        // Now we overwrite the whole static variable
        cutscene_introHurt7 = "* " + playerName + " huh?\n  That's a nice name.";
        // And you do have the expected result
        Console.WriteLine(cutscene_introHurt7);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. That's unfortunate there's no easier way to force a refresh but oh well.